# Как записать в файл введенный с клавиатуры текст, и вывести на экран содержимое файла (одну строку)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

```
stroka = input()

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(stroka)

readStr = open('test.txt', 'r')
print(readStr)

f.close()
```

---

Вот как получилось вывести содержимое файла:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
print(*f)
f.close()
```

---

Вот ответ на мой вопрос:

```
# 1. записать в файл, введенную с клавиатуры, строку 
# 2. вывести на экран содержимое файла 

f = open('test.txt','w+')
try:     
    stroka = input('введите строку для записи в файл: ')
    f.write(stroka)
    print(stroka)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `readline()`:

```
print(readStr.readline())
```

Подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/fajly-v-python-vvod-vyvod)

Comment: По вашей ссылке почитав, получилось вывести на экран содержимое файла. См. выше мой дополненный вопрос.

Comment: @Muriam Оцените ответ, пожалуйста, если он вам полезен.